# Android Studio FireStore collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.vedev.celebr8.activity.DBqueries$3$1.onComplete(DBqueries.java:162)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I have seen everywhere

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("PRODUCTS").document(String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("product_ID_"+x)))
.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            wishListModelList.add(new WishListModel(String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("product_image_1"))
                    , String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("product_title"))
                    , (long) task.getResult().get("free_coupons")
                    , String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("average_rating"))
                    , (Long) task.getResult().get("total_ratings")
                    , String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("product_price"))
                    , String.valueOf(task.getResult().get("cutted_price"))
                    , (boolean) task.getResult().get("COD")));

            MyWishListFragment.wishListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I expected the output of this code will help me to see my WishList in my ecommerce app but it's not working.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of the questions. It's hard to identify code, error and the actual question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: In the 9th line where the first casting of long "(long)" happens there i got the error

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand you want to retrieve your Firestore collections. I search in the documentation and I found how you can [connect and retrieve your collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java-android) using java.